# How do I specify an execution delay with the Google Cloud Tasks Go client library?

Tags: go, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-tasks

I followed [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#go) to create a task, and read "You can also fine-tune the configuration for the task, like scheduling a time in the future when it should be executed".

However it's still not clear to me how to effectively schedule the execution in a delay (a `time.Duration`) chosen by me, e.g. "please trigger the cleanup of these objects in 20 minutes".

The relevant LOCs are the `CreateTaskRequest` creation, and the `Task` creation:

```
        req := &taskspb.CreateTaskRequest{
                Parent: queuePath,
                Task: &taskspb.Task{
                        MessageType: &taskspb.Task_HttpRequest{
                                HttpRequest: &taskspb.HttpRequest{
                                        HttpMethod: taskspb.HttpMethod_POST,
                                        Url:        url,
                                },
                        },
                },
        }
```

```
        createdTask, err := client.CreateTask(ctx, req)
```

Should I consider using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) for this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Cloud Scheduler for this.

What you're looking for is the field [tasks.Task](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/tasks/v2#Task)`.ScheduleTime`, which has type *[timestamppb.Timestamp](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp).

Converting your `time.Duration` into a `*timestamppb.Timestamp` date in the future is pretty straightforward (here, ignoring any subsecond precision):

```
        var d time.Duration = 20 * time.Minute
            
        ts := &timestamppb.Timestamp{
            Seconds: time.Now().Add(d).Unix(),
        },

        req := &taskspb.CreateTaskRequest{
                Parent: queuePath,
                Task: &taskspb.Task{
                        MessageType: &taskspb.Task_HttpRequest{
                                HttpRequest: &taskspb.HttpRequest{
                                        HttpMethod: taskspb.HttpMethod_POST,
                                        Url:        url,
                                },
                        },
                        ScheduleTime: ts,
                },
        }
```

The above applies to the [API v2](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/cloudtasks/apiv2).

Comment: Answering your very own question in less than a minute. That's really fast!

Comment: @Frenchcooc yes, it's an encouraged thing, per https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer